# Drupal - Add custom html in li to menu ul?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

Is there any way to write some html (as you might in a block), and have that html appear as a menu item?

My situation is that I want some text that is not a link to say 'Follow us on:', and then I want 2 images which are both links to twitter and facebook.

Menu html cant do this as it requires any html you write to be part of a link, and to be the same link for that menu entry.
http://drupal.org/project/menu_html

I really want the html I add to be within the menu list.
Thanks

UPDATE
Code doesn't work well in the comments so im adding it here. This link seemed to be the closest to what you were suggesting:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item/6

So I added this to my template.php:

```
function localhost_petitpim_menu_item($link, $has_children, $menu = '', $in_active_trail = FALSE, $extra_class = NULL) {
  $class = ($menu ? 'expanded' : ($has_children ? 'collapsed' : 'leaf'));
  if (!empty($extra_class)) {
    $class .= ' ' . $extra_class;
  }
  if ($in_active_trail) {
    $class .= 'active-trail myactive';
  }
  return '<li class="' . $class . '">' . $link . $menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

All ive done is add a class of 'myactive' so I can see if its working. My theme name is 'localhost_petitpim'. Ive refreshed the cache. My theme is set to 'Rebuild theme registry on every page.' I cant see the new class being applied. Have I done something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply hard-code text and linked images in your tpl.php file(s).
Just put html block with desired code in tpl.php after menu. Make new wraper around menu & block if current html structure of your theme is not supporting this solution. Block should be floated right or displayed inline depending on HTML+CSS of your theme.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not a nice solution, but it works.

1. Add two dummy menu entrys to your menu.
2. Override the `theme_menu_link` method by implementing `phptemplate_menu_link` in your `template.php` file.
3. Inside the phptemplate_menu_link filter for your dummy entry and replace them with what ever html code you like.

Comment: How can I do this? Is this link talking about the same thing?:
http://www.computerminds.co.uk/adding-custom-markup-drupal-menu-items

Comment: Yes, it's using the same theme hook to tweak the final html output of the menu items.

Comment: Ive looked into this a bit, I know its quite standard high-end Drupal theming but im getting confused. Is there a way of getting the standard code into the override, so I can see what additions I want to make? Its not seeing the standard code thats confusing me as I dont know how Drupal is generating this stuff. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's easy and actually a good starting point. Copy the theme_menu_link method to your template.php file and rename it to phptemplate_menu_link. No you have to reset the theme registery to tell Drupal to call your copied implementation, see http://drupal.org/node/337176 for this.

Comment: We also offer payed Drupal suport, if this is an option for you.

Comment: Is for theme_menu_link for D7? Im on D6.

Comment: Ive been looking at the menu system API http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/group/menu/6 I thought this looked promising but it didnt work for me http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/6

Comment: Use `phptemplate_menu_link` instead of `localhost_petitpim_menu_item`.

Comment: Ive tried just changing 'function localhost_petitpim_menu_item' to 'function phptemplate_menu_link' in my template.php but this doesn't do anything either. Which of these should I be working from?: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/group/menu/6

Comment: theme_menu_tree appears to create the opening and closing ul tags, so could I just add my li before the closing tag?: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/6

Comment: @BetaRide I went to your site to try and contact you about paid support but I couldn't find a contact form or email. Ive posted my requirements in the drupal paid forum here: http://drupal.org/node/1113472